# Check if JSON object is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object

```
var values = {"220":{"287":19,"total":19},"":{"240":76,"total":76},"total":95};
```

and I'm not able to check if `values[item]['total']` is defined.

item is variable got from selectbox value, basically I'm trying to make if else statement, I need to check if `values[item]['total']` is defined, I have 2 scenarios

1. item is 220, or another number which goes in "" (json object is generated with php, in this case it has 220 and "", because it doesnt have "color" value, only size, but usally it have correct values)
2. and in my case item value is the one in {} brackets - for example 287 and 240

This code :

```
if ( typeof values[item]['total'] === 'undefined' ) {
    console.log('undefined');
}
```

throws: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `in` to check:

```
if (item in values && 'total' in values[item]) {
    console.log('defined');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That error will be caused when the value of `item` does not match any of the properties it will return null, and then you try to access a property of it but you can't because the item is null.

What you should do is check both parts for undefined:

```
if ( typeof values[item] === 'undefined' || typeof values[item]['total'] === 'undefined') {
    console.log('undefined');
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/pKd3K/)

Comment: +1 for actually explaining what happens. And providing code based on the OP's.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```
 if ( typeof values[item]!== 'undefined' && 
      values[item].hasOwnProperty('total')===false ) 
     { 
        console.log('Total undefined'); 
     }
```

Note: Make sure you are passing a string for item. so it will be compiled as item["220"] and not item[220]. In JavaScript object indexers are accessed by string names

Comment: this code throws: Uncought TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined

Comment: @kriss.andrejevs make sure you are passing string "220" to a `item` and not a number 220

Comment: @Murali you pass the if *only* if the object is not defined. You need to check for `!==`.

Comment: @Murali Just that your logging output now should say "defined", because that's what you're testing for.

Comment: I think you have kind of missed the problem and suggested a fix that isn't required... although you have addressed the issue after the above comments, it still feels a bit "off course"

Comment: @musefan, yes i missed the OP. Corrected. Thank you

Comment: @Murali: you have changed it back to being wrong again... the problem is when `item` does not match, so `values[item]` will be null, so you can't call functions/properties on it